# display the content of table in checkbox form

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a table called "project_name" in my database called "encrypt_decrypt". The table contains only 1 column called "name" which contains different values of name (ex : p1, p2, p3...). I have to retrieve this values(p1,p2,p3..) from my database and display it on a registration form with each value displaying one below the other having a checkbox with it so that user can select any of the name while registering! How do i do this in php ???

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="reg" action="code_exec2.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
<table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><div align="right" style="white-space:nowrap" >Please select the project:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right"><input type="checkbox" name="project[]" ></div></td>
<td><?php
session_start();
include('connection2.php');
$row=mysql_query("select * from project_name");
$array= array();
$output = mysql_fetch_assoc($row);
 while($output){
     $array[] = $output;
    }
print_r($array);
?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right"><input type="checkbox" name="Select all" 
 value="select all" onclick="toggle(this)"></div></td>
<td>Select all</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right"></div></td>
<td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like you're just starting the project. I suggest you to work with `mysqli_*` or `PDO` as `mysql_*` is obsolete and not available from PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this and i got:  any ways thanks  for all your help :)

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$r=mysql_query("select distinct name from project_name");
$ProdArray=array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($r)) {
array_push($ProdArray,$row->name);
}
foreach($ProdArray as $p) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><div align='right'>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='project[]' value=" .$p. " />";
echo "</div></td>";
echo "<td>$p</td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

}
    ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from project_name");
$checkboxes=array();
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $checkboxes[]='<input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="'.$r['name'].'">'.$r['name'].'<br />';
}
```

Then echo below wherever you want the checkboxes to appear.

```
echo implode("\n",$checkboxes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that your connection to db is correct, you need to change the way you display results:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('connection2.php');
$row=mysql_query("select * from project_name");
$array= array();
 while($output = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)){ 
//now you have row with name, and you need to display each name with new tr:
?>        
<tr>
<td><div align="right"><input type="checkbox" name="project[]" value="<?php echo $output['name'] ?>"></div></td> 
<td><?php echo $output['name'] ?></td>
</tr>
 <?php   } // closing while loop
?>
```

Note that I added `value` to checkbox - if you want to do something with checked project, you have to know which one it was.

And remember taht mysql_ functions are depreated! You should use PDO or mysqli_ instead